# How to combine multiple Excel files but keep number of tabs

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have the following files that I am working with:

'2010sales.xlsx' (w/ the following sheet names: countries, products, and pricing)

'2011sales.xlsx' (w/ the following sheet names: countries, products, and pricing)

These files are essentially the same but different values corresponding to the year

I want to combine these files into the following:

'totalsales.xlsx' (w/ the following sheet names: countries, products, and pricing)

I have used the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

excel1 = '2010sales.xlsx'
excel2 = '2011sales.xlsx'
output = 'totalsales.xlsx'
df1 = pd.read_excel(excel1,sheet_name=None)
df2 = pd.read_excel(excel2,sheet_name=None)
combine = [df1,df2]
join=pd.concat(combine)
print(join)
join.to_excel(output)
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'dict'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

How can I combine these files while keep the same number of tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Your `df1` and `df2` aren't dataframes - they're dictionaries of sheet_name->sheet_data, so you could after loading them (whatever you choose to call them) try:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(output) as xlsout:
    for sheet_name, rows in df1.items():
        xlsout.to_excel(pd.concat([rows, df2[sheet_name]]), sheet_name, index=False)
```

Comment: I tried using this but I get the following error: "IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible". None of the sheets in the excel files are hidden though.

Comment: @Tonypz16 move the concat out the .to_excel and assign it to `combos` or something and see what `print(sheet_name, len(combos))` shows inside the loop - you're looking for it definitely writing things and possibly empty dataframes...